# Не центрует карту при открытии балуна

Tags: yandex-maps-api

С помощью getClosestTo получаю ближайшую точку и открываю балун:

```
ymaps.geoQuery(map.geoObjects).getClosestTo(locationPosition).balloon.open();
```

Но в отличии от примера https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsbox/2.1/find_closest_object/ у меня карта центрируется на точке. Что я делаю не так?

Comment: В примере карта тоже центрируется на точке)

Comment: Вроде все логично, это так и должно работать.

Answer (score 0):

За приближение к точке при открытии балуна отвечает его опция [autoPan](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsapi/doc/2.1/ref/reference/IBalloonManager.html#method_detail__autoPan). Настроить её по своему усмотрению можно, задав параметр глобально:

```
myMap.options.set('balloonAutoPan',false)
```

Такая строка кода в [упомянутом примере](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsbox/2.1/find_closest_object/) из песочницы Яндекс отключит прокрутку карты к метке, на которой открылся балун.